# Como saber o "tamanho" (quantidade de propriedades/atributos) de um objeto em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Suponha um objeto da seguinte forma:

```
vendas = {
    obs1:{
        Venda1:{Regiao:"Norte", Valor: 200}, 
        Venda2:{Regiao:"Sul", Valor:100}
    }, 
    obs2:{
        Venda1:{Regiao:"Norte", Valor: 50}, 
        Venda2:{Regiao:"Sul", Valor:20}
    }
}
```

Quais as formas de saber o "tamanho" do objeto, isto é, quantos "outros objetos" há dentro dele?

Comment: Por "tamanho" você quer dizer o número de bytes que o objeto ocupa em memória ou a quantidade de atributos? Talvez seja bacana editar a pergunta pra deixar mais claro. :) (pergunto isso porque entendi na sua resposta que o retorno com `Object.keys` é `2`)

Comment: @LuizVieira Quantidade de atributos, realmente não está claro! Editei para tentar melhorar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uma solução que encontrei foi utilizar a função `Object.keys()` em conjunto com `length`:

```
Object.keys(vendas).length //2, isto é Obs1 e Obs2

Object.keys(vendas.obs1).length //2, isto é, Venda1 e Venda2
```

Em browsers mais antigos talvez seja necessário fazer um loop pelo objeto:

```
var tamanho= 0;  
for (var i in vendas) {
    if (vendas.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        tamanho++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso. A outra solução (aliás, a única em implementações antigas como a do IE8) é fazer um loop `for..in` sobre as propriedades e contá-las "na unha".

Comment: @bfavaretto adicionei esta solução também